# Can Joomla have forms on front end with SQL server housing tables on backend?

Tags: sql-server, joomla, ms-access-2013

Yes, I am a learning Access and am not familiar with Joomla!, but I am working on creating an Access database (in Access 2013) so multiple users can have a user friendly way to look at and edit our data via forms, use the queries, etc. We are trying to transfer our Schedule worksheet from Excel to Access.

1) My co-worker is working on Joomla! version 3.6.2, and I would like to know if Joomla! has forms and the ability to do queries, etc., like Access, so we can use Joomla! on the front end and house our tables in SQL server on the back end?

2) I don't know if Joomla! is compatible with SQL server, but do you recommend us sticking with Access as our database or using Joomla! on the front end? We have other things in Joomla! and would like to see if we can view and make changes to our Schedule via forms and queries, etc. in Joomla!, making it the one place to go to for all of our needs.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Access is a good tool for learning what a relational database is but I suspect there are less limitations with SQL (or MySQL) in terms of the amount of records, the size of the database and with sharing the data with multiple users.

There are quite a few [forms extensions](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms) that enable you to not only submit data to the database but to also retrieve it in whatever way you wish (sometimes with a little custom coding).

[Joomla supports SQL](https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements) but MySQL is probably the preferred database.